# FullCalendar overflow menu (div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, fullcalendar

I have problem fullcalendar flows over the bottom menu like on image. In Chrome I fixed by additing postion:sticky, but on safary that doesn't work. Any sugestions?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: It's like you're showing a pic of your car to the mechanic and tell him "it just doesn't start, any suggestions?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using -

```
contentHeight: 'auto',
```

If **`auto`** is specified, the view's contents will assume a natural height and no scrollbars will be used. I think it will work out for you.

**[Source link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/contentHeight/)**

Comment: @Joker123 did you removed  `postion:sticky,` if no then please do try that.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for us so we can check it!  I tried this in my fullcalender and its working fine.